# Count number of GroupBy rows

Tags: ultrawingrid

When I group the ultragrid by the column [Col], I'd like to get the count of the group by rows, I mean after group by the column [Col], there may finally come two group by rows. How can I get the count of the group by rows?

Comment: The phrase "there may finally come two group by rows" is unclear to me if you'd like to clarify what you mean :)

Answer (score 1):

The Rows collection of the Grid will contain the GroupByRows after the grouping is done so you could check grid.Rows.Count.

Comment: If you don't have multiple bands (or are grouping by a column in the outer-most band) this is simplest and work great!

Answer (score 0):

For the whole grid I was able to grab all the `ChildBands` for all the top-level rows and then count the number of `IsGroupByRow` rows they had:

```
var childBands = UltraGrid1.Rows.SelectMany(x => x.ChildBands.Cast<UltraGridChildBand());
var allChildRows = childBands.SelectMany(y => y.Rows));
var groupByRowCount = allChildRows.Count(x => x.IsGroupByRow);
```

If you have a specific row you want to check, you can do the following:

```
var childBands = specificRow.ChildBands.Cast<UltraGridChildBand>();
var groupByRowCount = childBands.SelectMany(x => x.Rows).Count(x => x.IsGroupByRow)
```

This feels like a really round-about way to get to child row objects... surely there's a better way.

---

My example doesn't work if you're grouping by more than one column. The issue seems to be that, quoting Mike Saltzman from [this post](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/13029/48414.aspx#48414):

> A GroupByRow will never have a ChildBands collection. ChildBands only exist on data rows. What you need to do is cast the row into an UltraGridGroupByRow and use the Rows collection to get its child rows.

There's an [example on Infragistics website](http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Support/KnowledgeBaseArticle.Aspx?ArticleID=7694) that I believe is very close to what you're looking for.